# Malaysia Custom Regulation

Tags: customs-and-immigration, regulations, malaysia, malaysian-citizens

I will go back Malaysia this summer. My family asks me to buy Starbuck Tumblers for them. How many can I bring back to Malaysia?

I found the custom regulation in other website. It says, " all other goods, incl. gifts and souvenirs up to a total value of max. MYR 400".

But, there is another regulation, "The items can only be imported duty free if the following conditions are met: the articles are imported by the visitor on his person or his baggage; non-alien residents stay in Malaysia more than 72 hours; nationals and residents of Malaysia have left the country for more than 72 hours. "

I am Malaysian and I am studying in the U.S. I lhave left the country for more than 72 hours.

How many can I bring back without getting charge on tax?

Comment: Are you sure about "non-alien residents stay in Malaysia more than 72 hours", or do you mean "non-resident aliens"?

Comment: I am Malaysian. I think the 3rd category would fit me. I am not sure what is the different between non-alien residents and non-resident aliens. I am Chinese.

Comment: A non-alien resident is someone who lives in Malaysia and is Malaysian. A non-resident alien is someone who is not Malaysian and does not live in Malaysia.

Comment: I think I am a non-alien resident. I live in Malaysia and is Malaysian. I have been living in Malaysia more than 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.customs.gov.my/en/tp) government page is fairly clear. As a returning resident or a visitor intending to stay more than 72 hours you may bring total goods amounting to MYR 400 without paying duty (plus some items like new clothing). If you bring more than that (currently a bit over US $100 value), you pay 30% on the excess, so if you brought MYR 450 worth you would pay 15 ringgits.

It's not clear whether the "value" includes US sales tax, but typically the exchange rate used would be that in effect when you arrive, not when you purchased the items.

Comment: I only pay for how much I exceed? For instance, It is worth 500, I pay RM150? I bought all the tumblers online, how do they know the price?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says. You should bring a receipt to show the cost, or at least bring a copy of the listing showing the price.

Comment: What if I don't bring receipt... The listing can be made by myself? lol